Unit Testing a Bloc in Flutter: States Not Emitting as Expected
I'm working on a Flutter application using the BLoC pattern, and I'm currently facing an issue with my AuthenticationBloc during unit testing. My unit test is supposed to emit two states: loading and success, but it only emits the loading state. Here’s the relevant code for my AuthenticationBloc and the unit test:
dart

class AuthenticationBloc
    extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  AuthenticationBloc(this.registerUseCase, this.refreshTokenUseCase)
      : super(AuthenticationState.initial()) {
    on<Register>(onRegister);
  }
  final RegisterUseCase registerUseCase;
  final RefreshTokenUseCase refreshTokenUseCase;

  Future<void> onRegister(
      Register event, Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) async {
    //  await HiveStorage().clearBox();
    emit(AuthenticationState(state: StateStatus.loading));
    if (event.isConnected) {
      bool isValidUser = false;
      UserData? storageUserData = await getUserStorage(event);
      final now = DateTime.now();
      if (storageUserData == null) {
        await HiveStorage().clearBox();
        // await HiveStorage().putLastDate(date: now);
        isValidUser = false;
      } else {
        final lastDate = await HiveStorage().getLastDate();
        if (lastDate != null) {
          if (lastDate.add(const Duration(days: 15)).isBefore(now)) {
            await HiveStorage().clearBox();
            isValidUser = false;
            // await HiveStorage().putLastDate(date: now);
          } else {
            isValidUser = true;
          }
        } else {
          await HiveStorage().clearBox();
          isValidUser = false;
          // await HiveStorage().putLastDate(date: now);
        }
      }
      String? storageFirebaseToken = await getFirebaseToken();
      if (isValidUser && storageFirebaseToken != null) {
        if (event.registerRequest.firebaseToken != storageFirebaseToken) {
          Completer<void> completer = Completer<void>();
          try {
            RefreshTokenRequest refreshTokenRequest = RefreshTokenRequest(
                firebaseToken: event.registerRequest.firebaseToken);
            Endpoints.token = storageUserData!.token!;
            String? token;
            final result =
                await refreshTokenUseCase.call(params: refreshTokenRequest);
            result.fold((l) {
              emit(state.copyWith(
                  state: StateStatus.success, userData: storageUserData));
              completer.complete();
            }, (r) async {
              token = r;
              await HiveStorage().putFirebaseToken(
                  firebaseToken: event.registerRequest.firebaseToken);
              storageUserData = storageUserData!.copyWith(token: token);
              await HiveStorage().putUserData(
                  userData:
                      UserDateHiveMapper().toHiveUserData(storageUserData!));
              emit(state.copyWith(
                  state: StateStatus.success, userData: storageUserData));

              completer.complete();
            });
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
            emit(state.copyWith(
                state: StateStatus.success, userData: storageUserData));
            completer.complete();
          }
          await completer.future;
        } else {
          emit(state.copyWith(
              state: StateStatus.success, userData: storageUserData));
        }
      } else {
        Completer<void> completer = Completer<void>();
        try {
          UserData? userData;
          final result =
              await registerUseCase.call(params: event.registerRequest);
          result.fold((l) {
            emit(state.copyWith(state: StateStatus.error));
            completer.complete();
          }, (r) async {
            userData = r;

            await HiveStorage()
                .putFirebaseToken(
                    firebaseToken: event.registerRequest.firebaseToken)
                .whenComplete(() {
              return HiveStorage().putLastDate(date: now);
            }).whenComplete(() {
              return HiveStorage().putUserData(
                  userData: UserDateHiveMapper().toHiveUserData(userData!));
            });

            emit(
                state.copyWith(state: StateStatus.success, userData: userData));
            completer.complete();
          });
        } catch (e) {
          emit(state.copyWith(state: StateStatus.error));
          completer.complete();
        }
        await completer.future;
      }
    } else {
      await getStorageUserData(event, emit);
    }
  }

  Future<UserData?> getUserStorage(Register event) async {
    UserData? storageUserData = await HiveStorage().getUserData();
    return storageUserData != null
        ? storageUserData.user!.msisdn == event.registerRequest.msisdn
            ? storageUserData
            : null
        : null;
  }

  Future<String?> getFirebaseToken() async {
    String? storageFirebaseToken = await HiveStorage().getFirebaseToken();
    return storageFirebaseToken;
  }

  Future<void> getStorageUserData(
      Register event, Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) async {
    Completer<void> completer = Completer<void>();
    UserData? storageUserData = await getUserStorage(event);
    final now = DateTime.now();
    if (storageUserData != null) {
      DateTime? lastDate = await HiveStorage().getLastDate();
      if (lastDate != null) {
        if (lastDate.add(const Duration(days: 15)).isBefore(now)) {
          await HiveStorage().clearBox();
          emit(state.copyWith(state: StateStatus.error));
          completer.complete();
        } else {
          emit(state.copyWith(
              state: StateStatus.success, userData: storageUserData));
          completer.complete();
        }
      } else {
        await HiveStorage().clearBox();
        emit(state.copyWith(state: StateStatus.error));
        completer.complete();
      }
    } else {
      await HiveStorage().clearBox();
      emit(state.copyWith(state: StateStatus.error));
      completer.complete();
    }
    await completer.future;
  }
}

Future<void> initHiveForTest() async {
  final directory = Directory.systemTemp.createTempSync();
  Hive.init(directory.path);
  registerAdapters();
  await Hive.openBox('orange_im');
}

void registerAdapters() {
  Hive.registerAdapter(HiveUserDataAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(HiveProfileAdapter());
}

void main() async {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await initHiveForTest();

  late AuthenticationBloc authenticationBloc;
  late MockRegisterUseCase mockRegisterUseCase;
  late MockHiveStorage mockHiveStorage;
  late MockRefreshTokenUseCase mockRefreshTokenUseCase;
  final userDateHiveMapper = UserDateHiveMapper();
  setUp(() async {
    mockRegisterUseCase = MockRegisterUseCase();
    mockHiveStorage = MockHiveStorage();
    mockRefreshTokenUseCase = MockRefreshTokenUseCase();

    when(mockHiveStorage.putUserData(userData: anyNamed('userData')))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value());
    when(mockHiveStorage.putUserData(userData: anyNamed('userData')))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value());
    when(mockHiveStorage.putLastDate(date: anyNamed('date')))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value());
    authenticationBloc =
        AuthenticationBloc(mockRegisterUseCase, mockRefreshTokenUseCase);
  });

  tearDown(() async {
    await Hive.box('orange_im').clear();
    await authenticationBloc.close();
  });

  group('AuthenticationBloc - onRegister event', () {
    const tRegisterRequest = RegisterRequest(
      msisdn: 'msi123456',
      name: 'Joe Kae',
      avatarUrl: "http://example.com/avatar_test.png",
      firebaseToken: 'test_token1',
    );

    const tUserData = UserData(
      token: 'token',
      user: Profile(
        msisdn: "msi123456",
        name: "Joe Kae",
        isArchived: false,
        isCreator: false,
        deletedAt: null,
        avatarURL: "http://example.com/avatar_test.png",
        lastActive: null,
        isActive: false,
        orangeUser: null,
        isBlocked: false,
      ),
    );
    blocTest<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      'emits [success] when user data is retrieved from storage and date is valid',
      build: () {
        when(mockRegisterUseCase.call(params: anyNamed('params')))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => Right(tUserData));

        when(mockHiveStorage.getUserData()).thenAnswer((_) async => null);
        when(mockHiveStorage.getFirebaseToken())
            .thenAnswer((_) async => 'test_token1');

        when(mockHiveStorage.putFirebaseToken(
                firebaseToken: anyNamed('firebaseToken')))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value());

        // Convert UserData to HiveUserData using the mapper
        final hiveUserData = userDateHiveMapper.toHiveUserData(tUserData);

        when(mockHiveStorage.putUserData(userData: hiveUserData))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value()); // Store user data

        when(mockHiveStorage.putLastDate(date: anyNamed('date')))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value());

        return authenticationBloc;
      },
      act: (bloc) {
        bloc.add(
            Register(registerRequest: tRegisterRequest, isConnected: true));
      },
      expect: () => [
        AuthenticationState(state: StateStatus.loading), // Loading state
        AuthenticationState(state: StateStatus.success, userData: tUserData),
      ],
      verify: (bloc) {
        verifyNever(mockRegisterUseCase.call(params: tRegisterRequest))
            .called(1);
        verifyNever(
                mockHiveStorage.putFirebaseToken(firebaseToken: 'test_token1'))
            .called(1);
        // Verify user data was stored
        verifyNever(mockHiveStorage.putLastDate(date: anyNamed('date')))
            .called(1);
      },
    );
  });
}


Expected vs Actual Results
During testing, I expect the following sequence of states:
Expected:
[
  _$AuthenticationStateImpl:AuthenticationState(state: StateStatus.loading, userData: null),
  _$AuthenticationStateImpl:AuthenticationState(state: StateStatus.success, userData: UserData(...))
]

Actual:
[
  _$AuthenticationStateImpl:AuthenticationState(state: StateStatus.loading, userData: null)
]

